# News list items take me to 404 pages

Tags: html, wordpress

I've created a news page and used a shortcode to display the recent items (using recents news list plugin).

But when I click on an item to "Read more" I get taken to a 404 page?

Please see: http://www.utcoxfordshire.org.uk/news/

Even if I click "View post" on a recent update item from within the dashboard I also get a 404 error?

Comment: Do you have a index.html or .php file in your map of your [newspage](http://www.utcoxfordshire.org.uk/news/)

Comment: check your permalinks.make it /%post_name%/

Comment: Legendary that worked a treat!